# Unity - Accessing a UI's text through a Transform

Tags: unity, gui

I have this in my player's component list. The HungerTarget transform is the text box in the UI canvas. How would I change the UI's text here?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthHunger : MonoBehaviour {
    //public Transform HealthTarget; Not being used yet...
    public Transform HungerTarget;

void Start () {
}

void Update () {
    //set HungerTarget's text to ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Update () {
    HungerTarget.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Your text here";
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this? Blocks of code with no explanation don't make great answers.

Comment: Don't call GetComponent() in the Update loop, it'll run every frame and add a crap load of un-needed overhead. The correct way to do it is to cache it class level.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: change the type of your public variable!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthHunger : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text hungerText;

    void Update() {
        hungerText.text = "your text here";
    }
}
```

You can still drag your UI Text gameObject into this `public Text` field in the inspector, and Unity will choose the Text component from it automatically.

This has some advantages:

- Unity will guarantee that whatever is assigned to that field has a `Text` component.
- This requirement is visible to a level designer working in the editor, clearly communicating what the script needs to function without needing to read the code.
- No need to call `GetComponent<Text>()` every frame, or to set aside a variable to cache the result after calling it once.
- You can still get the `Transform` when you need it by writing `hungerText.transform` - this is substantially faster than a typical `GetComponent<>()` call, so you typically won't need to worry about caching this separately.

In general, when a script relies on an object referenced by an inspector field having a specific component, giving that field the specific type you want can help simplify the code and narrow down the types of bugs you might have to fix. (ie. it can still go wrong if we leave the field *blank*, but we can't assign the *wrong* kind of thing to it anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, don't call GetComponent every frame in the Update loop, cache the component and use it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthHunger : MonoBehaviour {
    //public Transform HealthTarget; Not being used yet...
    public Transform HungerTarget;
    private Text _uiText;


void Start () {
    _uiText = HungerTarget.GetComponent<Text>();
}

void Update () {
    _uiText.text = "Whatever you want";
}
}
```